# How to create a new view (tab) in jenkins programatically

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to create a new view on jenkins( using the plus symbol). Manually , you click the plus symbol enter values in 2-3 text boxes and a view gets created but I would like to do 
it using a program. Can anybody suggest me a way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way using a rubygem named jenkins_api_client  ( http://rubygems.org/gems/jenkins_api_client)